# How to encrypt a zpool in Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption, ubuntu-server, zfs

Does zfs on linux have a built in command to encrypt entire pools (or zfs file systems)?

If not - how should one proceed to do so?

(I'm running zfs on an Ubuntu Server 12.04LTE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, ZFS-native encryption is closed-source. There are multiple options available:

- [LUKS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/encryptedZfs)
- (other file-system-agnostic methods)
- File-based encryption on top of the FS, like [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/).

Setup is simple: Just do `mount -t ecryptfs /tank/private /tank/private`, it'll ask you a few questions and you're good to go.

The Arch Linux Wiki contains a comprehensive [comparison table of encryption methods](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Encryption#Comparison_table). The most important point about file-based encryption being:

> file metadata (number of files, dir structure, file sizes, permissions, mtimes, etc.) is *not* encrypted

Comment: As of June 2019 ZFSOnLinux 0.8.0 includes built-in support for encrypted datasets.